# Rails render select options from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, controller

View:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :company %><br />
<%= f.select :company, %w(A B C), :selected => 'B'%>
</div>
```

Controller where I want to render 'select options' (this is not the controller for my view):

```
def load_company_code
  @company_code = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Helper**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

You'll be better using a `helper`:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def company_codes
       [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
   end
end
```

You must remember that Rails is just a framework for Ruby (indeed, it's actually a [`gem`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails)), which means that although Rails has a huge amount of logic behind the scenes, in the end, it's the same as all other applications -- it will load a series of files which provide it with functionality

One of the problems you have is that including methods in `controllers` means those methods will *only* be accessible at the time of loading that specific controller. On the other hand, the *helpers* of Rails are loaded every time you run your application, thus allowing you to call their methods whenever you need:

```
<%= f.label :company %>
<%= f.select :company, company_codes, :selected => 'B'%>
```

--

**Framework**

To give you a brief overview on how this stuff works, you'll be best looking into the [MVC (Model View Controller) programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). This is one of the fundamental building-blocks of Rails, and allows you to create the most adaptable system:

[image]

Specifically, MVC means that each time your application receives a request, it will route the request to your *controller*, which will then build data from your *models*, showing that data in your *view*. The difference here is that in order to call the methods you want, the *classes* they belong to have to be loaded

As pictured above, only certain controller & model classes are loaded each request. If you wanted to call a method inside those, you would be able to so long as they were loaded at the time of the request. Alternatively, you'll want to load a class which is *always* present, you'll be able to invoke the method whenever you need

Answer (score 0):

What model is your form representing here? Usually it is not a good practice to keep this kind of data on your controllers. You should keep it in your model class, probably as a constant.

Supposing you have a Employee class, company is an attribute of Employee, and the form is for a employee object:

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
```

It would be good to keep the company codes as a constant of your employee class:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   COMPANY_CODES = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
end
```

And then, inside your form tag:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :company %><br />
  <%= f.select :company, Employee::COMPANY_CODES %>
</div>
```

Comment: what I need is to render the options that already exist from another controller to avoid DRY. Thanks for the help anyway. :)